# Java Webapp on Tomcat6 using libservlet3

Tags: tomcat, java, tomcat6, tomcat7, servlet

I am quite new to all this Java stuff. I Installed a bunch of War-Packed Webapps on a Ubuntu Machine with tomcat6. One of them does not work (skos-play), apparently because it needs libservlet3 and Tomcat6 comes with libservlet2.5.
For the other other apps, tomcat6 was recommended and I have no clue if they will work with 7 as well... before give it a try I wanted ask

Is there a possibility to tell a single Webapp libservlet-Library it should use so that I can use my tomcat6 but for that spefific app with libservlet3?

If not, is it possible (and would you recommend) to run an instance of tomcat6 and one of tomcat7 on the same machine?

Thank you very much for your help and best wishes!